# Remove lines from file

Tags: python, perl, text, awk, text-processing

I am doing some text processing on a unix system.  I have access to the command line on this machine and it has Python, Perl and the default text processing progams installed, awk etc.

I have a text file that looks like below:

```
2029754527851451717 
2029754527851451717 
2029754527851451717 
2029754527851451717 
2029754527851451717 
2029754527851451717 1232453488239 Tue Mar  3 10:47:44 2009
2029754527851451717 1232453488302 Tue Mar  3 10:47:44 2009
2029754527851451717 1232453488365 Tue Mar  3 10:47:44 2009
2895635937120524206 
2895635937120524206 
2895635937120524206 
2895635937120524206 
2895635937120524206 
2895635937120524206 
5622983575622325494 1232453323986 Thu Feb 12 15:57:49 2009
```

It is basically 3 rows: ID ID Date

I am looking to remove all the lines that do not have 2 ID's and a Date.  So the finising results will be like this:

```
2029754527851451717 1232453488239 Tue Mar  3 10:47:44 2009
2029754527851451717 1232453488302 Tue Mar  3 10:47:44 2009
2029754527851451717 1232453488365 Tue Mar  3 10:47:44 2009
5622983575622325494 1232453323986 Thu Feb 12 15:57:49 2009
```

How would you guys suggest doing this?  In total the text file is around 30,000 lines long.

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NF > 2' input_file > output_file
```

Comment: the equivalent perl being: perl -i -wane'print if @F > 6' input_file > output_file

Answer (score 8):

```
grep ':' filename
```

Answer (score 5):

```
with open(source_filename) as src:
    with open(dest_filename, 'w') as dst:
        for line in src:
            if len(line.split()) > 1:
                dst.write(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

With Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^([0-9]+\s+){2}.+$/' $filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Just working my perl here, but this might help as well:

```
perl -lane 'if (scalar(@F) == 3) { print @F;}' file >> file.out
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `scalar(@F) > 3` ?

Answer (score 2):

With Python:

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

p = re.compile('^\d*$')

for line in lines:
    if not p.search(line): print line,
```

Comment: You probably don't want to read in an entire 30000 line file.

Comment: @chills42: that's dinky.  max 60 bytes per line gives 1.7Mb.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk "NF>1" < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -lane 'print if($F[1])' file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed '/^[0-9]$/d'  filename
```

(might have to modify the pattern if the bad lines have trailing spaces). You can also use grep -v, which will omit the matched pattern.